# Interference between lme4 and nlme packages

Tags: r, lme4

I had this script:

```
mod<-lmList(log(indwgt)~log(lngtclass)| sex, data=mbsp)
```

that worked two weeks ago. Today I get

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'indwgt' not found
```

I feel it is due to interferences between lme4 and nlme, but I don't know how to remove nlme. If it is of any help, I tried this:

```
getAnywhere(lmList)

2 differing objects matching ‘lmList’ were found
in the following places
  package:lme4
  namespace:lme4
  namespace:nlme
```

but it is meaningless to me, apart from strengthening my feeling of interference between both packages. Any ideas? I have quit R, started again, load packages, updated packages, everything I could think of. Removing them basically does not work.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your answers!  the object mbsp is a data frame:

Answer (score 2):

It is true that there are two (slightly different) versions of `lmList` in the `lme4` and `nlme` packages.  If you have both loaded and you want to make sure you are using the `nlme` version of `lmList`, use `nlme::lmList`. *Or* unload the `lme4` package via `detach("package:lme4")`.  Vice versa, obviously, if you want to use the `lme4` version (`lme4::lmList`, `detach("package:nlme")`.  **However**, I don't actually see how having the wrong version of `lmList` could lead to the specific error you are getting. Posting the results of `str(mbsp)` would help ...

Comment: Hi Ben!   I did library(nmle)

Comment: Hi Ben! I did 'library(nmle)', then 'pkg <- "package:nlme"' and 'detach(pkg, character.only = TRUE)'. The other trick 'lme4::lmList' did not work.Still get the old error message 'indwgt not found'. mbsp is a dataframe with 9 variables, all numeric: str(mbsp)
'data.frame':   1538 obs. of  9 variables:
 $ haulno   : int  2 
 $ speccode : int  58 58 
 $ ind      : int  1 2 35 6 ...
 $ lngtclass: num  54 5 51 ...
 $ sex      : int  2 2 ...
 $ indwgt   : int  1150 810 970 ...
 $ subwgt   : int  8440  26060 ...
 $ nomb     : int  4 4 4 4 23 23 23 ...
 $ stratum  : int  379 379 379 379
???  LAr

Answer (score 1):

Your error message means that `indwgt` is not in `mbsp`.

Is it possible that you've made some change in the last two weeks that resulted in a subtle name change?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for your message. mbsp is a data frame and indwgt is one of the variables, numeric. The names are the first thing I checked -just in case! ;-)

Comment: Have you tried restarting R without loading nlme and lme4 then fitting a simple lm model? Doing so might help you diagnose if your error is due to something funky with your data frame, versus  bad behavior on the part of the two packages. If the error persists then try restarting, but only load nlme OR lme4 and see what happens.

Comment: Hi, Chris. Thanks for your message. I just did as you suggested, restarting without loading any of the packages, and the lm works fine. No problems to find the indwgt variable ;-) . Then I loaded lme4, run the lmList and got back to square one with the indwgt not found error message.

Comment: What happens if you drop the `log` statement around the `indgwt` variable? I'm just guessing now, but perhaps lmList is looking for an 'indgwt' object instead of `mbsp$indgwt`?

Comment: Hi,well, it works! but then the model is not good because the relationship between weight and length is not linear. It is actually the log() bit that causes the error blabla not found. Now I do not understand anything.

Comment: sounds like you need to dig into the particulars of `lmList`. As a kludge you could just create new columns ala `mbsp$log.indgwt <- log(mbsp$indgwt) etc...` and pass those to `lmList`. Why your original specification doesn't work might be a follow-up question for the gurus here.