# Why does a log() statement cause lmList to fail?

Tags: r, lme4

In working through this question: [Interference between lme4 and nlme packages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416696/interference-between-lme4-and-nlme-packages) the OP and I determined that wrapping the response vector in `log()` inside a call to `lme4::lmList` causes `lmList` to fail.

e.g.,

```
my.lmList.model <- lmList( log(response) ~ log(predictor) | group, mydata)
```

gives the response

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'response' not found
```

but if you first log the response and predictor it works fine, i.e.,

```
mydata$log.response <- log(mydata$response)
mydata$log.predictor <- log(mydata$predictor)
my.new.lmList.model <- lmList( log.response. ~ log.predictor | group, mydata)
```

Can someone explain why wrapping the response in log() in the first example doesn't work? It seems to me (at least intuitively) that it should.

Comment: sounds off the top of my head like an environment / reference problem. Have you tried the same trick with vanilla `lm` , checked the detailed documentation in the lme4 package, etc?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what answer you want.  The "why" is because that's how lmList is designed to function.  You already know the workaround.  Do you want to know how to rewrite lmList to have it not fail in such conditions?  It's not a simple function.  It might be best to write the package authors after carefully reading the documentation and looking through the function to see if this is intentional behaviour.